# Optimization under constraints - unique solution or not

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints, karush-kuhn-tucker

Say we have a problem such as minimize $f(x)$ such that $h(x)=0$ and $g(x) \leq0$. Let the minimum achieved under these constraints be $f(x^*) = p^*$. My question is:

If $f(x)$ is convex, are $p^*$ and $x^*$ unique? Why, why not? If in the general case they are not, are there any special/notable cases or any conditions on $f, g, h$ under which the solution is unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimizer $x^*$ is not in general unique. Try $f(x) = c$ where $c$ is a constant function. In fact, the minimum $p^*$ is not necessarily unique in general. The constraints $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ give a description of the set where you search for your minimum. If this $\mathbf{set}$ is convex, minimizing a convex function $f(x)$ over this set leads to a unique minimum $p^*$.

The problem will be convex (that is to say, you'll be minimizing over a convex set) if, for example:

- The $g(x)$ are convex functions.
- The $h(x)$ are affine functions.

As for when the minimizer is unique, there are a whole host of conditions that can make this true. When $f(x)$ is "strongly convex", which is a stronger condition than convexity, and you minimize it over a convex set (such as, for example, constraints with the above criterion) the minimizer $x^*$ is unique. A unique minimizer, of course, guarantees a unique minimum.

Strong convexity of $f(x)$ isn't the only way to get a unique minimizer, but its a common one and has a nice geometric intuition. For a second differentiable function $f$, strong convexity is equivalent to having the eigenvalues of the Hessian bounded from below by a positive number. In general, it essentially says that at every point on the domain, $f(x) $ can be bounded from below by a term that's quadratic in $x$ (aka a parabola).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! To make sure I understand correctly:
1. If $f(x)$ is strictly convex, the minimizer $x^*$ is always unique no matter if $g(x)$ is convex and $h(x)$ is affine/convex? Or $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ do matter in this case?
2. If $f(x)$ is convex, the minimizer $x^*$ is unique only if $g(x)$ is convex and $h(x)$ is affine/convex?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, see my edit above. Let me know if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks, clear now!